# Istio outbound traffic fails

Tags: kubernetes, mesh, istio

I am running Istio 1.14 minimal on K8s 1.22

I am testing different outbound connections from inside the mesh and they all fail with errors like:

```
Execution of class com.microsoft.aad.msal4j.AcquireTokenByAuthorizationGrantSupplier failed.
com.microsoft.aad.msal4j.MsalClientException: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Remote host terminated the handshake
```

or

```
Cannot send curl request: SSL connect error - trying again
```

As a test, I tried a curl from inside the istio-enabled pod:

```
curl https://www.google.com #this failed
curl http://www.google.com #this worked
```

Then, after some reading I created a ServiceEntry:

```
apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1alpha3
kind: ServiceEntry
metadata:
  name: google
spec:
  hosts:
  - www.google.com
  ports:
  - number: 443
    name: https
    protocol: HTTPS
  resolution: DNS
  location: MESH_EXTERNAL
```

This solved the issue and now curl works for both http and https towards google.

My question is how can I extrapolate this in order for all outbound traffic to be allowed? I cannot create Service Entries for all external resources I am trying to connect to.

Sorry for the bad explanation, but I am very new to both K8s and Istio.

Answer (score 1):

Set **meshConfig.outboundTrafficPolicy.mode** to **ALLOW_ANY** in your Istio installation configuration.

https://istio.io/latest/docs/reference/config/istio.mesh.v1alpha1/#MeshConfig-OutboundTrafficPolicy-Mode

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the same problem as well,the ServiceEntry provide right DNS to the outbound traffic, so I guess maybe the DNS was wrong for me, my solutions is change the log level of istio-proxy to debug

```
istioctl -n my-namespace proxy-config log pod-name --level envoy:debug
```

then I found my outbound traffic resolved to a wrong dns, here is the log

> debug envoy filter    [C24436] Creating connection to cluster outbound|443||xxxx-svc.xyz.svc.cluster.local

then I goto the xyz namespace delete the xxxx-svc, then all https outbound traffic works for me without ServiceEntry